# Validating lengh of a phone with PHP

Tags: php, validation, string-length

I'm trying to validate the length of a phone number staying within a range. Let's say at least 9 characters but not more than 12 so I can get international phone numbers.

I tried several things but none of them work.

The option below for instance validates correctly that it has not letter, however it doesn't matter the length of the number I introduce, I always get the Error Message: "Your phone number needs to have 9-11 numbers" even if I introduce a 9, 10 or 11 eleven digits number.

Thank you so much

```
if (empty($_POST["cellphone"])) {
 $cellphoneErr = "Cell Phone is required";
} else {
 $cellphone = test_input($_POST["cellphone"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$cellphone)) {
  $cellphoneErr = "Only numbers allow";
}
 elseif(strlen($_POST["cellphone"] < 9) || strlen($_POST["cellphone"] > 11)){
 $cellphoneErr = "Your phone number needs to have 9-11 numbers";
}
}
```

Comment: some countries use less than 9 digits

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match()` with quantifier `{min,max}`:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{9,11}$/",$cellphone)) {
  $cellphoneErr = "Has to be 9 to 11 numbers.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`elseif(strlen($_POST["cellphone"] < 9) || strlen($_POST["cellphone"] > 11)){`

Should be:

`elseif(strlen($_POST["cellphone"]) < 9 || strlen($_POST["cellphone"]) > 11){`

Your parenthesis are wrong.